# How to integrate a shopify site into react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

Hi am new to react native. Could you please any one help me . How to build an app shopify site in to react native.

[react native npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shopify) am refer this site to install that module in react native app and use like that usage only but i cannot get result.

So any one please help me to resolve this solution . How to integrate a shopify site in to react native to build a mobile app

Comment: Did you follow the steps as given in the package? Try **./gradlew clean** inside android  and do npm install again and check if not working please let me know what error are you getting exactly????

Comment: Is there possible to build an app what ever done in shopify site that be integrate to react native by this module react-native-shopify. For any other solution is available for this.

Comment: Yes you can include the functionality in your app like how ever you want

Comment: If you don't mind can you please share sample single functionality. for example get products .

Comment: Try out this example: https://medium.com/react-native-development/how-to-use-the-flatlist-component-react-native-basics-92c482816fe6 you can implement something like this for whatever you want like products etc

Comment: ya ok its showing up you used another app. But i need for Shopify to connect in react native for that only no solution get till now

Comment: Checkout...if this could help: https://support.reactaz.com/techstore-react-native-shopify-full-integration-app-docs/

Comment: that one he bought a code from another party but am needed how to do that one.